# Find if a term is included in a value of an object which is into an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
myApp.filter("patientFilter", function() {
    return function(rs, searchTerm) {
    var addPatient;
    var selectedPatients = [];
    for(i=0; i<rs.length; i++) {
    addPatient = false;
    if(rs[i].firstName == searchTerm) || if(rs[i].lastName == searchTerm{ //WRONG
    addPatient = true;
}

if (addUser){
  selectedPatients.push(rs[i]); 
}
```

I Want to find if the searchTerm is a part of firstName OR lastName values. Of course the equality I have in the code doesn't solve the problem. Any ideas?

I get rs[i].firstName, rs[i].lastName from an http get request in an api.

Comment: post your code and not a picture of your code

Comment: You can basically call on firstname the includes method assuming firstName is a string https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: could you share how are you using the filter in the html template?

Comment: @sebasaenz I'm not sure how I will use it. I think something like that: `ng-repeat="pat in patients | patientFilter: search.name track by $index"  ` search.model is the ng-model value

Answer (score 0):

#### String.prototype.includes()

On strings you can call the [includes method](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Here an example

```js
const str = 'To be, or not to be, that is the question.'

console.log(str.includes('To be'))        // true
console.log(str.includes('question'))     // true
console.log(str.includes('nonexistent'))  // false
console.log(str.includes('To be', 1))     // false
console.log(str.includes('TO BE'))        // false
console.log(str.includes(''))             // true
```

So you can write

```
if(rs[i].firstName.includes(searchTerm)) || if(rs[i].lastName.includes(searchTerm)){
```